# php Designer on win 10 can't save php file as .php, but save as .py

Tags: php, phpdesigner

i use win 10 and php Design 8.1.2

when i create a php file and i click save, file type is not php extension (*.php), but it is python (*.py)

please help me fix it

Comment: It's just a text file.  Change the extension out on the filesystem.

Comment: when i created a new file, i select php, but when save, .py is default